# Java method return file data, inputstream or byte array, which is better?

Tags: java, inputstream

I need to load many binary files less than 1MB with file path, like this: loadFile(String path);
should it return byte[] or Inputstream? I think return byte[] will take up a lot of memory, and I don't know how about return ByteArrayInputStream or event FileInputream because I have no idea when to close InputStream.
Thanks.

Comment: This is a decision only you, the programmer, can make.

Comment: And what do you want to _do_ with this data you load?

Comment: returning a `ByteArrayInputStream` or a `byte[]` array directly is the same thing memory wise. A `ByteArrayInputStream` simply wraps an array and allows you to access it like a stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both options have pitfalls:

- `Streams` are stateful. You must describe the behaviour in comments but you cannot programmaticly constraint some things like: How many bytes have already been read before returning the stream instance.  Furthermore when using `Streams` as return value or method parameter it is unclear who is responsible for closing the stream. I would generally avoid using `Streams` as return value or method parameter whenever possible.
- `byte[]` forces you to store everything in memory. This may be ok for small things but it does not scale well. Furthermore arrays are mutable and that's problematic. You must work with defensive copies (horrible with much data) or you break encapsulation because your returned mutable array can be changed from outside.

My advice would be to use `Suppliers` for resources when they need to be fired around between method calls. In this particular case I would use [Guava ByteSource](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteSource.html).

When it is not necessary to fire things like this around then just do it the way Michael Wilkowski posted it.

Comment: Up vote to "....When it is not necessary to fire things like this around then just do it the way Michael Wilkowski posted it."

Answer (score 3):

It is good practice to use input streams instead of arrays (input streams are used internally anyway). The best practice is to use Closeable functionality available in new Java now, which automatically closes input stream after leaving try() {} clause, i.e.:

```
try (FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(new File(path))) {
    //...reading code comes here
}
```

Comment: Hey, you are using Java 7... Therefore `try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(path)))`

Comment: You're right. I am so used to intellisense that do not remember exactly the methods and constructors :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good at english. I should use more codes to read file in each fileReader methods and close file in current method, and should not just call all-in-one method "ByteArrayInputStream loadFile(String path)" to do that for each fileReader method. my english... --!

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you should learn how to close an inputStream, it's not hard at all:

```
inputStream.close();
```

That said, to use `InputStreams` or a `byte[]` really depends on your application.

A one-fits-all solution is certainly to use `inputStreams` (that way, **you'll decide later** wether to load it fully or on chunks) but if you will always use the read data as a whole (for example, reading bitmaps), there's nothing wrong with your function being self-contained and returning the whole byte array.