# REST service returning byte[] or InputStream

Tags: java, arrays, rest, inputstream

I know [there are some resources talking about `byte[]` and `InputStream`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306327/java-method-return-file-data-inputstream-or-byte-array-which-is-better), but I am still in confusion which one to use returning an image from a REST service.

I have a `GET` REST method which returns an image. Should I return as `byte[]` or `InputStream`? What is the advantage of one over the other?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/images/{imageId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getEventImage(@PathVariable("imageId") String imageId) {
```

Comment: Where do you get the image from? If [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) and `Connection` is still open, then use `InputStream` straight from [`getBinaryStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream-java.lang.String-). If you use `@Transaction` on a service layer, so `Connection` is closed before getting back to action handler, then use `byte[]`, unless image is so *huge* you don't want it in memory. If you get image from resource, use `InputStream`, e.g. `FileInputStream` or `Resource.getInputStream()`.

Comment: Thanks, Andreas! I am getting the image from a different service and I get it as byte[]. So, I think returning as byte[] is appropriate in my case.

Comment: If it's already a `byte[]`, then use it as-is, definitely.

Comment: I am just wondering if there is any downside returning InputStream to the byte[].

Comment: `byte[]` vs `InputStream`: With `byte[]`, the full size is known and HTTP response can set `Content-Length` and send data in one block. With `InputStream`, the size is not known, so HTTP response must use [chunking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) to send data in smaller blocks, adding overhead.